# How do I limit the number of getty processes started?

Tags: freebsd, getty

I've got a FreeBSD (9.2) box that I'm trying to strip down as lightweight as possible.  It's running on a VM server, so other than ttyv0, we don't ever use the console.  I'd like (if possible and reasonable) to not start the extra getty processes that run ttyv1 through ttyv7.  How do I accomplish that in a FreeBSD supported manner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can edit the `/etc/inittab` file and comment out the unneeded ttys.
Take a look at the inittab manpage [here](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=inittab&manpath=Red+Hat+Linux%2Fi386+9&format=html).

If `inittab` doesn't exist, take a look at the `/etc/ttys` file. It also has a manpage [here](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?ttys).

Comment: FreeBSD 9.2 does not have appear to have an inittab file anywhere on the filesystem.

Comment: I edited the answer, hope the ttys file helps.

Comment: ttys it is!  Was able to turn "off" in there, but I imagine commenting them out probably would have worked too.

Comment: On Ubuntu (server edition) their is multiple ttys files e.g `/etc/init/tty6.conf`  I guess I should comment  out `start on runlevel [23] and not-container`  or change it to stop.